# What algorithms are there for taking an uncompressed audio file and calculating the frequencies present in the audio file?

Tags: signal-processing

I need an algorithm that can take an uncompressed audio file and determine the frequencies of the sounds represented by the audio file. (Let's say there are at most 6 sounds as an example)

Comment: This appears to boil down to: Without noise reduction, what 6 sine waves will, when added together, produce the audio file?

Comment: The standard algorithm is FFT, applied on short snippets (STFT).

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com